# division by the sum of all elements of a column

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I want to divide each element of a column in a matrix by the sum of the column's elements like this:

```
M=[1 2
   3 8]

c=[0.25 0.2
   0.75 0.8]
```

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `bsxfun` to apply a function to each column of the matrix:

```
M = [1 2;
     3 8];

c = bsxfun(@rdivide, M, sum(M,1))
```

`rdivide` is the same as `./` or element-wise division. In this case we're using it to divide each element of the column vector by a scalar.

Result:

```
c =

   0.25000   0.20000
   0.75000   0.80000
```

Comment: If an answer helps you, consider accepting it. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. You might also want to take the [tour].